# Luke 4:13, does (for a time) mean there will be a second confrontation between Jesus and the Devil?

Tags: luke

Luke 4:13 (DRB):

> And all the temptation being ended, the devil departed from him **for a time**.

Does (departed from him for a time) mean that there will be another (temptation) or confrontation between Jesus and the Devil?

"For a time" has the following variations in other English versions:

- until an opportune time. (NIV), (ESV).
- until the next opportunity came. (NLT).
- for a season. (KJV), (ASV).
- for a while. (CEV), (GNT).
- until another time. (ISV).
- until a more opportune time. (NET Bible).

Thus, if there will be another confrontation between Jesus and the Devil, will it be a seductive, temptuous or what?

Comment: The Devil entered into Judas, Luke 22:3. And Judas, in betraying Jesus, kissed him, Luke 22:48. Thus, was Jesus betrayed to the authorities, and so to the cross of crucifixion.

Comment: @NigelJ do you mean that the Devil entering Judas and kissing Jesus is the second confrontation?, Is it a temptuous confrontation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jesus temptations in the desert were not the first or last time Jesus had to face temptations from Satan; although it was one of the greatest.  I am certain that as a child he had been tempted to do wrong on many occasions.

Jesus temptations in the desert was Satan's effort to derail Jesus' earthly ministry before its started.  It failed.  Concerning Jesus' temptations (collectively), were are also told in Heb 4:14, 15

> Therefore, since we have a great high priest who has passed through
>   the heavens, Jesus the Son of God, let us hold fast our confession.
>   For we do not have a high priest who cannot sympathize with our
>   weaknesses, but One who has been tempted in all things as we are, yet
>   without sin.

Other occasions on which Jesus was tempted included:

- In the garden of Gethsemane where Jesus asked not to go through with His great sacrifice on the cross.  He sweated great drops of blood in His immense distress (Luke 22:44)
- later, after praying when Peter cut off the servant's ear, most people would have been tempted to use His divine power to get away, especially as the Devil who had entered Judas (John 13:2) was kissing Jesus.  But Jesus remained calm and healed the servant's ear.
- Jesus records that He had had encounters with the devil, or the "prince of the air" but that devil was unsuccessful in tempting Jesus (John 14:30)
- Of Jesus many encounters with demonic forces, I note that on at least one occasion He spoke to them such as in Mark 5:9 where thousands of devils were in His presence; But Jesus righteousness made them depart.

I am sure there were many other occasions during the ministry of Jesus, after His temptations in the desert, that demonic forces tempted Him.

Comment: Perceiving then that they were about to come and take him by force to make him king, Jesus withdrew again to the mountain by himself. (John 6:15, ESV) Here and the context afterward is similar temptation.  We could keep pointing out more.

Comment: Completely agree - there must have been many times.  Thanks Perry.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different confrontations with Satan in the future that the passage may relate to:  the temptation of Jesus during His Passion and/or the temptation of those who persecuted and betrayed Him.

---

The Greek phrase is ἄχρι καιροῦ (*archi kairou*).  The word καιρός (*kairos*) here might be better translated here as *opportunity*.<sup>1</sup>  The usually hyper-literal *Orthodox New Testament* translates the phrase *until an opportune time*.

Greek commentators on this verse in antiquity seemed to understand the second occasion to have been the time of the Cross.  One commentator writes:

> And not without meaning are the words, *he departed from Him for a time*.  The devil attacks the Lord by means of two passions, pleasure and grief.  He attachd the lord with pleasure when he led Him up onto the mountain.  Then the devil *departed from Him for a time*, that is, until the time of the Cross, when the devil attacked Him again, this time with grief.<sup>2</sup>

Along these lines, the Russian Orthodox Archbishop Averky Taushev (1906-1976) made a connection with Christ's Agony in the Garden, described in John 17:

> At the same time, this agony occurred without a doubt also because the
>   Lord took upon Himself all the sins of the world, and took them to the
>   cross. That which the whole world should have been feeling on account
>   of its sinfulness now was concentrated on Him alone! It is also not
>   out of the realm of possibility that the devil, who had left Him after
>   the temptations “until an opportune time” (Luke 4:13), now returned
>   with new temptations, trying to dissuade Him from His coming Passion,
>   although without success. The sorrow of Christ the Saviour was also a
>   result of the knowledge of human cruelty, humanity’s lack of gratitude
>   to God.<sup>3</sup>

---

Augustine suggested that the devil returned in those who later persecuted Jesus:

> Satan will return.  He will enter Judas and will make him betray his master. He will bring along the Jews, not flattering now, but raging. Taking possession of his own instruments, he will cry out with the tongues of all of them, “Crucify him, crucify him!” (*Sermon CCLXXXIV*)

Ephraim the Syrian offers a similar interpretation in his commentary on the *Diatessaron* (a 2nd century Syriac harmony of the Gospels).  Another modern Eastern Orthodox commentator, Lawrence Farley, writes:

> For Satan departed *only until an* appointed *time and an opportune
>   moment* (Gr. *kairos*).  For Luke such a time came with the betrayal
>   of Judas, when Christ was betrayed into the hands of His foes.  Then
>   Satan would tear and sift the disciples like wheat (22:31); that would
>   be the hour for Satan to exercise his dark authority (22:53).  But for
>   now, he had been decisively vanquished.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>See, e.g., Swanson's *Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains: Greek*</sup>
<sup>2.</sup> <sup>Theophylact of Ohrid, *Explanation of the Holy Gospel According to St. Luke* (tr. from Greek; Chrysostom Press, 1997), p.49</sup>
<sup>3.</sup> <sup>*The Four Gospels: Commentary on the Holy Scripture of the New Testament* (tr. from Russian; Holy Trinity Seminary Press, 2015), p.214</sup>
<sup>4.</sup> <sup>*The Gospel of Luke: Good News for the Poor* (Ancient Faith Publishing, 2010), p.100-101</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course he had a time of peace after successfully tempted 3 times without sin. Thats expected to be in our life too.
God never can be tempted neither tempts anyone. But the Gospel teach "we must suffer temptations and tribulations before we enter to the Kingdom>. I say this because Jesus the Son of God was is our example of life . He was of course tempted but never commit a sin (that why satan let him in peace for a while).
So we see that jesus afer water Baptism and receiving the Holy Spirit , God let him be tempted by satan and then (only then) he went out started preaching the Gospel.
That why Jesus came in the world , to  and that inloudes live  a perfect life without never give up to any fleshy or demonic temptation.

Some temptations include:

Ηebrews 2:18 *For in that **he himself hath suffered being tempted**, he is able to succour them that are tempted.*

4:15 *For we have not an high priest which cannot be touched with the feeling of our infirmities; **but was in all points tempted like as** [we are, yet] without sin.*

Luke 22:28 ***Ye are they which have continued with me in my temptations.***

Μat.16:1 The Pharisees also with the Sadducees came, and tempting desired him that he would shew them a sign from heaven.

Ματ.1623 *But he turned, and said unto Peter, **Get thee behind me, Satan**: thou art an offence unto me: for thou savourest not the things that be of God, but those that be of men.* ¨

So yes Jesus was (he had tobe ) tempted like every man with the exception he never committed a sin. He was :
1)Tempted by satan directly
2)through men (which were od the devil)
3)and by the flesh or his own will (for example when he pray to God that <> 
*Sorry for my Enlgish.

Answer (score 1):

Hereafter I will not talk much with you: for the prince of this world cometh, and hath nothing in me. John 14:30
Then entered Satan into Judas surnamed Iscariot, being of the number of the twelve. Luke 22:3
These are 2 passages of written scripture detailing Satanic activity in Jesus presence and I'm sure all of his emnity against our Lord is not even written!!